# How to create a new data frame out of a combination between previous data and code results?

Tags: r

I have two data frames: one contains the food items consumed by patients with quatity (column for patients and each food item in a colunm) and the second is the value of (Flavonoids, phenolic acids, stilbenes, lignans, and other phenols) in 100g of the food item, also each class of phenols in a column.
I wrote a code that calculates the total value of each phenol class, it is a multiplication of the quantity consumed of each food item by the value of the phenol class in 100g of the food item.

Now I want to create a new data frame that gathers the patient column with columns for each phenol class containg the results of the multiplication.
The goal is to have final numbers on how much did the patient consumed flavonoids, phenolic acids, Stilbenes, lignans, and other phenols.
How should I express this on Rstudio?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. It is hard to tell without a minimal, reproducible example of your data that we can copy and paste. See this post for a guide: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example Please edit your question and add example data, so we can present a concise solution. Also, please post your attemps to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.